# Compiled Binding (x:Bind) to a resource key

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

Quick question, is it possible to bind to a resource key with compiled binding, like you would do with traditional binding?

i.e.
Traditional Binding

```
<Page.Resources>
   <local:DataSource x:Key="Data"/>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="myColl" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, Path=Colleges}" ItemsPath="Campuses" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Compiled Binding

I tried it and I know it doesn't work, obviously it's looking for the Property "Data" on the page and not the resource.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DataSource x:Key="Data"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="myColl" Source="{x:Bind Data.Colleges}" ItemsPath="Campuses" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

So is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using compiled binding means, as the name suggests, that the binding expression is validated at compile time and must thus be strongly typed. This means that the path **needs** to exist as a *property* on the context and will not work as a resource.

For {x:Bind} to work, declare your DataSource as a property in code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public DataSource Data { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data = new DataSource();
    }
}
```

Then remove your Data resource from your resources and you're done.